# tool to suggest index references

Tags: indexing

Is there a tool that will read through the existing index entries and then search through the document for additional locations where index words/phrases are used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a start, but by no means complete, and probably not even particularly good Python. It will flag any lines in a source file where an indexed term occurs, but is not immediately followed by `\index{term}`.

## Example master file (214458.tex):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\include{\jobname-1}
\include{\jobname-2}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

## Included chapters (214458-1 and 214458-2.tex):

```
\chapter{One}

To solve various problems in physics, it can be advantageous
to express any arbitrary piecewise-smooth function as a Fourier Series\index{Fourier Series}
composed of multiples of sine and cosine functions.
```

and

```
\chapter{Two}

To solve even more problems\index{problems} in physics\index{physics}, it can be advantageous
to express any arbitrary piecewise-smooth function as a different Fourier Series
composed of multiples of sine and cosine functions.
```

Make sure to run latex on the document before trying the following script (otherwise, there's no index file to compare against).

## Python script (indexwords.py):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

### Usage: indexwords.py indexfile sourcefile

import re, sys

indexEntryPattern = '\\indexentry{([A-Za-z ]+)}'

with open(sys.argv[1]) as index:
    indexLines = index.readlines()

with open(sys.argv[2]) as source:
    sourceLines = source.readlines()

lineDict={}
for indexEntry in indexLines:
    match = re.search(indexEntryPattern, indexEntry)

    if match:
        term = match.groups()[0]
        # print "Searching source for unindexed '%s' entries:" % (term)

        incompletePattern = "%s" % (term)
        completePattern = "%s\\\\index{%s}" % (term, term)
        lineNumber=1
        for sourceLine in sourceLines:
            termFound = re.search(incompletePattern, sourceLine)
            termIndexed = re.search(completePattern, sourceLine)
            if termFound and not termIndexed:
                # print "Line %d: %s" % (lineNumber, sourceLine)
                if lineNumber in lineDict:
                    lineDict[lineNumber].append(term)
                else:
                    lineDict[lineNumber] = [term]
            lineNumber = lineNumber+1

for entry in lineDict:
    print "On line %d, add entries for %s" % (entry, lineDict[entry])
```

## Usage:

### Windows with Python installed:

Save indexwords.py into the same folder as your TeX and index files. Then open a command prompt, change directories to that folder, and run:

```
indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458.tex
indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458-1.tex
indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458-2.tex
```

### OS X or any other Linux/Unix system:

Save indexwords.py into the same folder as your TeX and index files. Then open a command prompt, change directories to that folder, and run:

```
chmod a+x indexwords.py
```

once to make the script executable.

Afterwards, at a command prompt, run:

```
./indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458.tex
./indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458-1.tex
./indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458-2.tex
```

## Example output:

```
E:\Users\mwr\Dropbox\Inbox\TeX.SE>.\indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458.tex

E:\Users\mwr\Dropbox\Inbox\TeX.SE>.\indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458-1.tex
On line 3, add entries for ['problems', 'physics']

E:\Users\mwr\Dropbox\Inbox\TeX.SE>.\indexwords.py 214458.idx 214458-2.tex
On line 4, add entries for ['Fourier Series']

E:\Users\mwr\Dropbox\Inbox\TeX.SE>
```

Comment: Nice answer. But you may want to add how to use the script (for people who can’t read the pearl code …)

Comment: Some documentation added.

Comment: Wow, this is terrific. Thanks! It may not be complete, but it does 90% of what I'd want it to do. And it might even give me the kick-start I've needed to start learning some python...

Comment: I'd recommend adding `if match:` after `match = ...` in case there is no matching text for a given index entry (e.g., if it's a multi-file document).

Comment: match is merely a means to extracting the term from the .idx file. In theory, it should always work. There may be another fix you have in mind.

Comment: When I run the script on a single file that's part of a multi-file source document, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./indexwords.py", line 20, in <module>
    term = match.groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`. I assumed this was because it's trying to access an element of `match` but `match` is empty. Adding the `if` statement fixed it. But it's likely I'm misunderstanding here -- this is my first foray into python.

Comment: Must be something else, since I've modified my example to be a multi-file document with no changes to the Python. Compare to yours?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19041/discussion-between-mike-renfro-and-grendelsdad).